# Using a method from a Python class as a PySpark user-defined function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to write a Python utility function that accepts an object of a locally-defined class, and uses one of that class's methods as a user-defined function (UDF), in a PySpark DataFrame `withColumn` call.  The utility function signature is:

```
 def spark_analyze(lp: LogProcessor):
```

In the `LogProcessor` class, I have a method that I'd like to use as a UDF.  The method definition is:

```
schema = StructType([
  StructField("total", IntegerType(), False),
  StructField("other", IntegerType(), False)
])

def ProcessLog(self, log_file):
    self.PrepareForLog()
    for event in pyspark_utils.spark_events_from_file(log_file):
      self.ProcessEvent(event)
      return [total, other]
```

In the `spark_analyze`, I do the following, where `lp` is the passed-in object of type `LogProcessor`:

```
@udf(lp.schema)
def lpf(lcm_file):
    lp.ProcessLog(lcm_file)
return (df.withColumn('results', lpf(col('logfile_dir')))
...
```

The produces a long Python stack trace, which starts like this:

/home/david/libs.zip/pyspark_utils.py in spark_analyze(lp)
    132     def lpf(lcm_file):
    133         lp.ProcessLog(lcm_file)
--> 134     return (df.withColumn('results', lpf(col('logfile_dir')))
    135               .withColumn('log name', spark_get_dataset_name(col('logfile_dir')))
    136               .select('log name', 'results.*')

/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py in wrapper(*args)
   1955         @functools.wraps(f)
   1956         def wrapper(*args):
-> 1957             return udf_obj(*args)
   1958 
   1959         wrapper.func = udf_obj.func

and ends with:

/home/david/libs.zip/pyspark_utils.py in spark_analyze(lp)
    132     def lpf(lcm_file):
    133         lp.ProcessLog(lcm_file)
--> 134     return (df.withColumn('results', lpf(col('logfile_dir')))
    135               .withColumn('log name', spark_get_dataset_name(col('logfile_dir')))
    136               .select('log name', 'results.*')

/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py in wrapper(*args)
   1955         @functools.wraps(f)
   1956         def wrapper(*args):
-> 1957             return udf_obj(*args)
   1958 
   1959         wrapper.func = udf_obj.func

I did some testing, and found that things work fine if I define my UDF right above the place where I pass it to `col`.  I also tried redefining the `ProcessLog` to just `return [0,0]`, and found that the problem did not go away.  So the problem seems to be that I'm using a passed-in class object's method as a UDF.  Is there another way to have a UDF be a method in a class?  Thanks for any help here!

Comment: Have you registered this UDF defined in class? , something like this ` sparkContext.udf.register("ProcessLog",LogProcessor.ProcessLog,"Return Type") ` and then later you should be able to invoke it as ` df.withColumn("Result","ProcessLog(col('logfile_dir')") .  And also change the method defintion to static. Try this if it works for you. I was able to invoke udf like above.

Comment: Ah, that is a good idea!  I ended up switching to a procedural style and just passing the function definition, which worked.  I suspect your version would work too!  Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that Usman Azhar suggested may work.  I ended up solving this by simply passing the definition of my UDF as an argument of my library function.